# Elasticsearch / Lucene: Determine total bytes used by field in index

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have a lucene index (generated by ES 6.X.X) and I want to understand how much storage space (bytes) each of my fields is consuming.

Does anyone know how I can figure out how many bytes it requires to store all of the values for a given field across all documents?  I have the index opened up in Luke, but I am new to that tool and it's not clear to me how I can answer this question.  Is there a better tool for this?

Comment: why would u want to know the size of each field, you do understand that in any indexed data structure size of each entry is irrelevant?

Comment: but you can of course get the size of whole index

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal I'm not interested in the size of a field for an individual document-- I want to know how much each field consumes in the entire index.  Some of the lucene data structures are column oriented, and I want to determine the amount of storage space consumed by each column.